# Let $N$ and $M$ be two digit numbers. Then the digits of $M^2$ are those of $N^2$, but reversed.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $N$ be a two digit number and let $M$ be the number formed from $M$ by reversing $N$'s digits. The digits of $M^2$ are precisely those of $N^2$, but reversed.

$Proof$:

> Since $N$ is a two digit number, we can write $N = 10a + b$ where $a$ and $b$ are the digits of $N$. Since $M$ is formed from $N$ by reversing digits, $M = 10b + a$.
>
> $N^2 = (10a + b)^2 = 100a^2 + 20ab + b^2 $. The digits of $N^2$ are $a^2, 2ab, b^2$.
>
> $M^2 = (10b + a)^2 = 100b^2 + 20ab + a^2$. The digits of $M^2$ are $b^2, 2ab, a^2$, exactly the reverse of $N^2$.

This proposition is false. Let $N$ be $15$. That means the proof above is not correct, but I can't see where exactly.

Comment: Carries?  Those values aren't usually going to be a single digit.

Comment: $b$ is a single digit, but $b^2$ might not be.  So the units digit of $N^2$ is not $b^2$; it is $b^2\bmod{10}$.  Your other claims about the digits of $M^2$ and $N^2$ are similarly wrong.

Comment: So, if $a = 7$, then the $N^2$'s digit in hundredth place would be 49 which is not a digit. Is this one of the reasons this proofs wrong?

Comment: The only numbers for which the statement is true, are 11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88, and 99.

Comment: No, it's true for 11 and 22 but false for 33 through 99. It's also true for 12, 13, 21, and 31. And even 10, 20, and 30 if suitably interpreted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Greg's examples and other comments point out this, can only be true if $a^2,2ab$ and $b^2$ are all less than $10$. Otherwise there is a carryover that spoils it, as your example shows...

Answer (score 1):

however there exists an infinite sequence of such numbers: we have

$12^2=144$

$102^2=10404$

$1002^2=1004004$

$10002^2=100040004$

$\dots\ \dots\ \dots$

and the same with digits reversed:

$21^2=441$

$201^2=40401$

$2001^2=4004001$

$20001^2=400040001$

$\dots\ \dots\ \dots$

Comment: I don't think this addresses the actual question.

Comment: Also, I remember reading on meta (I can't find the link) that there is nothing wrong with copying earlier answers you gave, but it is encouraged to add a link to the other answer. Here is it: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1184224/43288

Answer (score 0):

It is too late to answer but I asked a similar question .so I am starting from your steps.You are using the assumption that square of $N$ (and $M$) are $\textit{three digits}$.
Let $N^{2}=(10a+b)^{2}=100x+10y+z$ where $x,y,z$ are non negative integers and  $x,z \neq 0$.
Since $M^{2}$ is the reverse of $N^{2}$ then $M^{2}= 100z+10y+x$

If you are using one more assumption that $a>b$ then $N^{2}-M^{2}$ will lead to $a^{2}-b^{2} \leq 8$ because $x,z \neq 0$.

Now by substituting values foe $b$ and solving we get values for $a$.Then you can find result stated in starting of your problem is not even valid for all two digit numbers less then $33$ . Actually it holds good for only 21 and 31.If we use digits need not be distinct then result is very simple.

But I am not sure about two digit numbers whose square is a four digit number

Answer (score 0):

flip-square-paired ::

```
      961: 31 31
      169: 13 13
         
  1062961: 1031 1031
  1692601: 1301 1301

  1216609: 1103 1103
  9066121: 3011 3011

121066009: 11003 11003
900660121: 30011 30011
```

---

unpairable ::

```
     9931: 9931
     1399: 1399

   909091: 909091
   190909: 190909
```

usually a `9` inside the smaller number wrecks havoc on being a perfect flipped square (maybe whenever the larger number is leads with digits higher than `sqrt( 10^(2n+1) )`

the only ones  that seem to hold the pattern for a long while (not sure is it finite or not) :

> ```
>   1(0*)3
>   3(0*)1
> ```

other than that, I'm guessing it's somewhat governed by whether original number has sufficient `"blank space"` to prevent over propagation of carrying digits,

```
                                  103: 103
                                90601: 7 7 43 43
                                  301: 7 43
                                10609: 103 103

                                  163: 163
                                96562: 2 48281
                                  361: 19 19
                               123031: 123031
```

---

```
                                  337: 337
                               965311: 17 56783
                                  733: 733
                               982735: 5 13 13 1163

                                  367: 367
                               986431: 61 103 157
                                  763: 7 109
                               961285: 5 13 23 643
```

---

```
                                  397: 397
                               906751: 906751
                                  793: 13 61
                               948826: 2 474413

                                 1003: 17 59
                              9006001: 3001 3001
                                 3001: 3001
                              1006009: 17 17 59 59
```

---

```
                                 1091: 1091
                              1820911: 61 29851
                                 1901: 1901
                              1083163: 991 1093

                                 3337: 47 71
                             96553111: 773 124907
                                 7333: 7333
                             98827735: 5 4409 4483
```

---

```
                                 3373: 3373
                             92177311: 8317 11083
                                 3733: 3733
                             98253931: 17 17 127 2677

                                 7377: 3 2459
                             92102445: 3 3 5 2046721
                                 7737: 3 2579
                             96116895: 3 3 3 5 7 17 31 193
```

---

```
                                 7773: 3 2591
                             92591406: 2 3 3 5143967
                                 3777: 3 1259
                             92756241: 3 3 10306249

                                10091: 10091
                            182828101: 182828101
                                19001: 19001
                            100830163: 7 179 80471
```

---

```
                                10111: 10111
                            123232201: 17 17 653 653
                                11101: 17 653
                            102232321: 10111 10111

                                31203: 3 3 3467
                            902726379: 3 3 23 463 9419
                                30213: 3 3 3 3 373
                            963528219: 3 3 29 43 85853
```

---

```
                                37337: 37337
                           9651504931: 2381 4053551
                                73373: 239 307
                           9217953835: 5 19 89 211 5167

                                73777: 11 19 353
                           9275403445: 5 7 11 24091957
                                77737: 11 37 191
                           9611403406: 2 11 11 769 51647
```

---

```
                               109609: 109609
                          18823141021: 18823141021
                               906901: 906901
                         108324964228: 2 2 13 2083172389

                               123031: 123031
                          16962663151: 7 7 29 181 65951
                               130321: 19 19 19 19
                          14036538961: 5647 2485663
```

---

```
                               300001: 13 47 491
                          10000600009: 100003 100003
                               100003: 100003
                          90000600001: 13 13 47 47 491 491

                               906751: 906751
                         100673791228: 2 2 239 269 353 1109
                               157609: 397 397
                          18869504842: 2 23 43 9539689
```

---

```
                              1000003: 1000003
                        9000006000001: 853 853 3517 3517
                              3000001: 853 3517
                        1000006000009: 1000003 1000003

                             12000221: 103 116507
                      148840403500441: 599 248481474959
                             12200021: 523 23327
                      144004215048841: 7 7 283 863 12033221
```

---

```
                             30000001: 30000001
                      100000060000009: 13 13 769231 769231
                             10000003: 13 769231
                      900000060000001: 30000001 30000001
```

---

but these aren't pairable

```
                           3116666633: 3116666633
                  9866555521090163179: 43 167 334261 4110502619
                           3366666113: 3366666113
                 96782522461704443311: 168151 575569116221161
```

---

```
                        1000000000091: 1000000000091
            1828000000002810000000001: 131 66463 209954387754147317
                        1900000000001: 1900000000001
            1000000000083000000000163: 13 17 409 4183651 2644411089917
```

---

```
                     1636363636363633: 1636363636363633
      9868594041322312123140595867762: 2 23 41 28783064588527 181792751701721
                     3363636363636361: 3363636363636361
     12322314059586714867768594041311: 13 13 37 1755302387 1122669441140541401
```